# Debug error. abort() as been called. Why?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

In my programming class, we have the following problem :
The user inputs an integer number. The program must make the sum of that number
and that number reversed. In other words, let's say the user input 1920. Here's what the program must do :

1920+0291=2211

Here's the code I came up with :

```
int main()
{

    cout << "Entrer votre number entier" << endl;
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    string numberInverse = to_string(number);
    string numberComparatoire = numberInverse;
    for (unsigned compteur = 0; compteur <= numberInverse.length(); compteur++){
        numberInverse[compteur] = numberComparatoire[numberComparatoire.length() - compteur];
    }
    int numberInverseInt = stoi(numberInverse);
    int somme = number + numberInverseInt;
    cout << "Le number inversé est " << numberInverse << " et " << number << "+" << numberInverseInt << "=" << somme << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

The names of the of the variables and the outputs are in french but that's not important.

I can build the solution to my code but upon running it, let's say I input 1920, my program shows mw an error message saying it had to abort and I don't understand why. Please help :( I know this is probably a bit of a beginner question in programming so guide me in my learnings.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `compteur <= numberInverse.length();` Off by one error sent the program off the end of the string.

Comment: `numberComparatoire.length() - compteur` should be another off by one.

Comment: Instead of getting the number as an `int`, get it as an `std::string`. That makes reversing the digits easier.